# How do you search for real remote work friendly accommodations?

Tags: online-resources

In Vienna, Austria, I scored an Airbnb with a proper desk and a reasonably nice rotating chair, which is all I need. The usual "just sit at the kitchen table and work there" arrangement is not great for working for several hours. The "dedicated workspace" option on Airbnb and Booking.com, as far as I can see, mostly finds this less-than-ideal option.

How do you search for this? Hotel rooms, apartments - all is fair game. Surely there are remote workers travelling these days and some sort of forum of theirs? Is there a subreddit I missed? Because /r/digitalnomad is certainly not this. In specifics, this is about Lisbon, but I am also curious in general.

Comment: What about coworking spaces separate from accomodations ?

Comment: As an example, whenever a client wants me on site, I want an office with a door that closes. I am coding here, unwanted noise, movement, people are highly distracting. I have no idea how can people do serious work in a co-working space. It's obvious they can but I can't.

Comment: It seems a reasonable thing in general to want to search for, but I'm still not entirely sure what specifically you're looking for: a dedicated room, or just a good chair. Some hotels do advertise their suitability for businesspeople - I wonder if there are some chains that are particularly good at this (although often what a hotel considers acceptable for work is pretty crappy, as you say). So unless there is a site that has independent/customer ratings, I'm not sure how useful it would be.

Comment: Desk and chair. Doesn't need a dedicated room.

Comment: In my (admittedly rather limited) experience looking at AirBNB postings, they usually identify things like that, and if the photos aren't sufficient, you should be able to contact the property owner for more details such as the dimensions of a desk and a picture of the desk & chair. Particularly if you're looking for a longer term stay, I'd think most would be happy to oblige.